# Nuxt.js auth middleware problems

Tags: vue.js, authentication, nuxt.js, directus

I have created admin dashboard for one client. Project is created using Vue.js with Nuxt.js. Backend is Directus and it was created by my colleague.

Problem is that auth middleware is not working as I need.
When I log in, I save AUTH_TOKEN and REFRESH_TOKEN in cookies. Then, I am firing up one API call, if response.message is: 'Token expired', I send new API call with REFRESH_TOKEN to refresh. Then, from response I save new REFRESH_TOKEN and new AUTH_TOKEN to cookies again and if response is not 200, I redirect user to /login.

Here is my code (/middleware/authenticated.js):

```js
import authService from '../services/authService';

export default function ({ $cookies, redirect, store, $toast, $router }) {
      const access_token = $cookies.get('access_token');
      const refresh_token = $cookies.get('refresh_token');

      if (!access_token) {
        $cookies.remove('access_token');
        $cookies.remove('refresh_token');
        store.commit('RESET_USER');
        return redirect('/login');
      }
      if(access_token){
        store.commit('SET_USER');
        setInterval(function(){
          try{
              authService.retrieveCurrentUser({headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${access_token}`,
              }})
                .then(() => {
                  console.log('ok');
                })
                .catch ((error) => {
                  console.log('prvy catch error', error);
                  if(error.response.data.errors[0].message == 'Token expired.'){
                    const config = {
                        "refresh_token": refresh_token
                    }
                    authService.refreshToken(config)
                    .then((response) => {
                      $cookies.set('access_token', response.data.data.access_token);
                      $cookies.set('refresh_token', response.data.data.refresh_token);
                      store.commit('SET_USER');
                      return redirect();
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                      console.log('druhy catch error', err);
                      $cookies.remove('access_token');
                      $cookies.remove('refresh_token');
                      store.commit('RESET_USER');
                      $toast.error('Platnosť vášho prihlásenia vypršala, prihláste sa prosím znova.', { timeout: 5000 });
                      clearInterval(this);
                      return redirect('/login');
                    })
                  }
                })
              }
              catch (err){
                console.log('treti catch error', err);
                $cookies.remove('access_token');
                $cookies.remove('refresh_token');
                store.commit('RESET_USER');
                $toast.error('Platnosť vášho prihlásenia vypršala, prihláste sa prosím znova.', { timeout: 5000 });
                clearInterval(this);
                return redirect('/login');
              }
      }, 300000)
    }
};
```

Here is authService:

```js
import api from '@/services/api';

export default {
    login (credentials){
        return api().post('/auth/login', credentials);
    },
    refreshToken(config) {
        return api().post('/auth/refresh', config);
    },
    logout (refresh_token){
        return api().post('/auth/logout', refresh_token);
    },
    retrieveCurrentUser(refresh_token){
        return api().get('/users/me', refresh_token);
    }
};
```

And this is how I call middleware inside page:

```js
middleware: 'authenticated',
```

Also I need that setInterval because I want to check if token is still valid every 5 minutes.

When I use this code, I am receiving automatic log outs, or spamming of that toast notification.

Comment: First off, I'll probably rather use `async/await`. Then, you need to know that there is a [nuxt auth module](https://auth.nuxtjs.org/) that can help you achieve some of those things. Otherwise, using a `setInterval` is probably a bad idea overall because it is not working properly when it comes down to SPA where the intervals can stack one on top of the others. I rather use a cookie with a UNIX timestamp that would expire every 5min and check that. Maybe a websocket/alike could also be cleaner. Otherwise, apply the middleware globally to your nuxt app. Right now, hard to debug with just this.

Comment: I recommend trying to see what is not working more on details on your side. Use the network tab, Vue devtools and you can also probably follow some advices written above. Right now, we don't know what is working, the exact content of your method/etc. Also, give a read on how the whole event loop works, may be useful if you still want to stick to `setInterval`.